# Material UI multiple fonts through theme provider in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there option to provide multiple fonts in the theme provider in react, and than dynamically to apply one of the fonts on different elements/components via hooks or something else?

BR, Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can provide multiple fonts through the theme configuration.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    a: {
       fontFamily: "Roboto",
       fontSize: 12
    },
    b: {
       fontFamily: "Helvetica",
       fontSize: 14
    } 
  }
});

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <... />
</ThemeProvider>
```

And in your component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textA: {
    ...theme.typography.a,
  },
  textB: {
    ...theme.typography.b,
  }
}));

const Greeting = ({useA}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <p className={useA ? classes.textA : classes.textB}>Hey</p>;
};
```

If you don't want to create two class names you can also pass a property to `useStyles` and set the font inside the class according to this property.

Comment: Ah.. got it... i wasn't sure... i was thinking u can only provide just those options what theme provider give it to u...thanks...

Comment: Anybody know how to get this method of typography usage without type warnings (when using the non deprecated `createTheme()`) function?

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked using `createTheme`

```js
const theme = createTheme({
    ...
    typography: { fontFamily: 'Montserrat, Yekan' },
});
```